# google chrome connecting to internet

Tags: wcf, service

I have a rest wcf web service in .NET. The service runs on localhost, but does not work on iis server. It displays:

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to Ip address of my machine
```

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is that you have a firewall issue.  And your firewall is blocking chrome from connecting to your IIS.